# Como "capturar" dados Webservice (XML) em Java SE?

Tags: java, xml, web-service

Sou leigo no assunto webservice e preciso capturar os dados de um webservice que retorna algumas poucas informações.

O webservice é este: http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp?lat=-27.8161100&long=-50.3261100&format=xml

Eu achei bastante informação na internet mas apenas para Java EE e de maneiras bem complexas.

Comment: Java não é comigo, mas me parece que esse já é o arquivo de resposta. Se você efetuar o download desse XML é só trabalhar com ele. Mas o que digo é só um comentário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você irá precisar focar **em duas coisas** que irei descrever logo mais. Pelo que percebi você quer fazer um *request* para uma URL e **obter e interpretar a resposta**, que nesse caso é o XML que você mostrou. Além disso, você quer fazer isso em Java.

Estou partindo do pressuposto **que você ainda não tem nada para fazer essa tarefa**, por isso, vou dividir a resposta em duas partes: Fazendo o request a URL e Lendo e interpretando o XML de resposta.

## Fazendo um request em Java

Para obter o XML você irá precisar fazer um request para a URL http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp passando três parâmetros **via [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)**. Os parâmetros são:

- lat;
- long;
- format;

Passado os parâmetros e fazendo o request, você irá obter a resposta. O trecho de código abaixo mostra como fazer o request em Java:

```
private String fazRequest() throws IOException {
    String latitude = "-27.8161100";
    String longitude = "-50.3261100";
    String format = "xml";
    URL url = new URL("http://www.geoplugin.net/extras/location.gp");

    StringBuilder urlParametros = new StringBuilder();
    urlParametros.append("lat=").append(latitude);
    urlParametros.append("&long=").append(longitude);
    urlParametros.append("&format=").append(format);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParametros.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Deixo a tarefa de entender todo o código acima para você. Mas basicamente, ele faz um request GET para a URL passando os parâmetros necessários para se obter a resposta. A resposta é lida, convertida em String e retornada pelo método.

## Fazendo o *parse* do XML

Com a resposta obtida pelo método anterior, precisamos agora interpretar (fazer o parse) dessa resposta. Para isso, iremos usar o **[DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)** para ler e obter os textos que estão no XML. Veja abaixo como fazer isso:

```
private void parseXML(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    String lugar = doc.getElementsByTagName("geoplugin_place").item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(lugar);
    
    String regiao = doc.getElementsByTagName("geoplugin_region").item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(regiao);
    
    String pais = doc.getElementsByTagName("geoplugin_countryCode").item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(pais);
}
```

Também deixo o código acima para você estudar seus detalhes. O que é importante saber é como funciona a estrutura do XML (inclusive com repetição de tags) para você poder desenvolver um código mais robusto.

## Concluindo...

Os códigos acima foram feitos **apenas como exemplo didático**. Não me preocupei com validações, tratamento de exceções ou outros cenários que o XML pode conter. Apenas fiz um trecho de código especificamente para seu problema e para você entender como o Java atende o que você pediu.

Abaixo, estão alguns links que podem ajudar nessa sua jornada:

- [Reading XML Data into a DOM;](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)
- [Making requests froms Java;](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/making-http-requests-from-java/240160966)

Comment: Justamento o que eu precisava, muito obrigado.

Comment: Muito bom que ajudou! :)

Answer (score 1):

Daew **Giovani Raci Paganini** verifica o consumo do webservice [explicado pela caelum](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-jsf-web-services-design-patterns/acessando-um-web-service/#6-2-consumindo-dados-de-um-web-service) tambem este do netbeans[Cliente 1: Classe Java na Aplicação Java SE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws_pt_BR.html#Exercise_3_1). Bom aprendizado!!!

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia
o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter 
conteúdo aqui mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta;  
você poderia fazer isso?
Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! 
Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: 
[Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)