# Parser XML Webservice em Java

Tags: java, xml, web-service, netbeans, parser

Estou tendo problemas com retorno XML de um webservice ao tentar fazer o parser. A saída do Netbeans reclama desta forma:

> [Fatal Error] :1:13: O espaço em branco é obrigatório entre o destino da instrução de processamento e os dados.
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 13; O espaço em branco é obrigatório entre o destino da instrução de processamento e os dados.

O webservice é este: https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=11748933&retmode=xml

Eu fiz algumas pesquisas aqui para tentar encontrar alguma solução, mas encontrei apenas uma tópico no qual o código está quase idêntico ao meu.

[Link do tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33837/como-fazer-parse-de-uma-response-xml-de-web-service)

O erro acontece nesta conversão:

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(source);
```

Método completo do request:

```
private void aplicaMetodoXML() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    // conexão com o webservice
    StringBuilder xmlContent = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/epost.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=11237011");
    HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conexao.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    conexao.setDoInput(true);
    // tempo para requisição
    conexao.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conexao.connect();

    /* Pega o dado requisitado e joga na string */
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        xmlContent.append(scan.next());

    }

    //System.out.println(xmlContent);]

    // Trata conteúdo xml
    String res = xmlContent.toString();
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(res);
    InputSource source = new InputSource(sr);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // Aqui onde a exceção é chamada
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(source);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    String teste = doc.getElementsByTagName("AbstractText").item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println(teste);
}
```

Já tentei mas não consigo achar onde está o problema. Há alguma outra alternativa para fazer o parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resposta curta:**
Mude o conteúdo da sua condição `while` para

```
xmlContent.append(scan.next() + " ");
```

**Resposta longa:**
Você comentou o trecho de código que mais te ajudaria a resolver esse problema:

```
//System.out.println(xmlContent);
```

Imprimindo o conteúdo do seu xml, sem a alteração de um espaço vazio, o resultado é:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPEePostResultPUBLIC"-//NLM//DTDepost20090526//EN""https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20090526/epost.dtd"><ePostResult><QueryKey>1</QueryKey><WebEnv>NCID_1_213127966_130.14.18.48_9001_1559196845_1904740853_0MetA0_S_MegaStore</WebEnv></ePostResult>
```

Isso resulta em um xml mal formado. Adicionando um espaço a cada iteração vai formar um xml possível de ser lido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <!DOCTYPE ePostResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD epost 20090526//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20090526/epost.dtd"><ePostResult> <QueryKey>1</QueryKey> <WebEnv>NCID_1_48388134_130.14.22.33_9001_1559196975_1500027833_0MetA0_S_MegaStore</WebEnv> </ePostResult>
```

Comment: É isso aí, meu caro. Muito obrigado. Erro simples mas que acaba atrapalhando bastante. Principalmente pelo fato de eu não entender de XML, logo eu demoraria bastante para consertar - se é que eu conseguiria sozinho. Eu já tinha encontrado outras alternativas em Python, mas eu precisava dessa. Valeu, brother!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu! Mais importante que o erro em si, é entender o motivo que ele está acontecendo. Boa sorte ai!